# Why React setState is not triggering re-render?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use react and update properties with setState, however, it doesnt seem to re-render.

In the following code, you will see that the onStart and onComplete use setState to update the style property.

The property gets updated, but the style does not get changed in the dom, despite my render function appearing to be set up in the correct way?

```
export default class FirstScene extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        let self=this;
        this.state = { 
            style:{display:'hidden'}
        };
        this.mainTimeline= new TimelineMax({repeat:0,paused:true,
            onStart:function(){
                self.setState({style:{display:'block'}})
            }.bind(self),
            onComplete:function(){
                self.setState({style:{display:'hidden'}})
                console.log(this.state);
            }.bind(self)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={this.state.style} >test hey</div>
        )
    }

};
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Do onStart and onComplete ever get called?

Comment: they both are called, in fact, it logs the updated state value cwhen I do console.log(self.state) in the onComplete

Comment: Shouldn't it be `display: none` instead of `hidden`? Did you check the inspector to see if that element has `display: hidden` set? But it had a strikethrough because it's not a valid property value?

Comment: Wow! @cfraser that was it!  All that frustration and it was just some incorrect css! Man! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, initialization like this is better handled in the `componentDidMount()` method, so it's guaranteed that the component exists before the state is modified.

```js
export default class FirstScene extends React.Component {

  state = {
    style: {
      display: 'hidden'
    },
    mainTimeline: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const mainTimeline = new TimelineMax({
      repeat: 0,
      paused: true,
      onStart: () => {
        this.setState({
          style: {
            display: 'block'
          }
        })
      }.bind(self),
      onComplete: () => {
        this.setState({
          style: {
            display: 'hidden'
          }
        })
        console.log(this.state);
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      mainTimeline
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={this.state.style}>test hey</div>;
  }

};
```

Also, side note, using es6 arrow functions in your `onStart` and `onComplete` callbacks, you can avoid having to bind and trap a reference to `this`.

Comment: Well, I have updated my code with your suggestion, it still does not want to update the style in the dom despite logging out the updated value from line 37: https://jsfiddle.net/qds5r5zn/

Answer (score 1):

The constructor should be used only to initialize the state. You should not call this.setState in the contructor you should indeed try to move `TimelineMax` to `componentDidMount`. Moreover because this.setState is asynchronous calling it multiple times won't work e.g.

```
class Counter extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            //initial state set up
            this.state = {value:0}
        }
        componentDidMount(){
            //updating state, OUTPUT will be 1
            this.setState({value:this.state.value+1})
            this.setState({value:this.state.value+1})
            this.setState({value:this.state.value+1})
            this.setState({value:this.state.value+1})
        }
        render(){
            return <div>Message:{this.state.value}</div>
        }
    }
```

I believe this is why your module doesn't work. So you should either use the callback to this.SetState that is triggered after the state is updated or use `componentDidUpdate`
[docs ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `TimelineMax` in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. It might be that callbacks are executed before component is mounted.

Comment: Moving it into `componentDidMount` doesnt appear to fix it, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: could you provide here your code after moving it to `componentDidMount`?

Comment: One more thing, component's `setState` method is asynchronous. Logging `this.state` immediately after `setState` call will log old value.
You can pass callback to `setState`, which will be executed after state is updated
 `this.setState({style:{display:'block'}}, () => console.log(this.state))`

Comment: Thanks again for getting back to me Michal... I cleaned it up a little based on your suggestion and from another commenter, here is the updated: https://jsfiddle.net/qds5r5zn/

Comment: Have a look at my codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mqYpNJ#anon-login